# Changing input controls of MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC application which takes input from the arrow keys. I also have a hand gesture recognition code. I want to integrate these two so that I can control the MFC application with the output of my hand gesture program instead of the arrow keys. But I cant find any main function in the MFC application, any ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: why do you need a main function?

Comment: I think I will have to make a separate thread for the hand gesture function, so for that I need a main function

Comment: If you need some place to initialize something I think `CWinApp::InitInstance` is what you searching for it.

Comment: I need to add a function which will run side by side the main game programme....should I use threading for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an MFC program start execution, MFC framework first call `CWinApp::InitInstance`(usually call this function of you app that derived from `CWinApp`), so you can do program initialization here, and you can put cleanup code in `CWinApp::ExitInstance`